# DatePicker disappears after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, postback

I have an asp:TextBox associated to a jquery DatePicker. This input has a onTextChangedEvent that updates a Literal Control.

All this code is inside an UpdatePanel so the Literal Control changes but the page doesn't refresh.

The problem I'm facing is that when the event fires, the image that displays the DatePicker disappears. Here's a piece of my code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:TextBox runat="server" OnTextChanged="EditFromDate_TextChanged"
        AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>

    </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Then I have:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#EditFromDate").datepicker({ ... });
});
```

Should I put the code that initiates the DatePicker elsewhere? 
I've tried placing it in Page Load using Page.RegisterStartup but same result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `pageLoad`, it fires on partial postbacks:

```
   function pageLoad() { 
      $("#EditFromDate").datepicker({ ... });

   }
```

$(document).ready() and pageLoad() are not the same!

Comment: Thanks!! So, when does $(document).ready() fire? And why putting this code in Page_Load event didn't work?

Comment: Check out the article. If you put document.ready code in RegisterStartupScript on postback it will work as well.

Comment: And now the link links to shady pdf sites.